# ¿Por qué se escriben cadenas de texto entre comillas en archivo escrito usando un shell y java?

Tags: java, shell

Buen día, tengo un problema al momento de escribir un fichero de texto desde un archivo shell, el cual recibe parametros desde un método en java. Aquí se encuentra el código shell que escribe sobre el fichero de texto

```
#!/bin/bash
# SITI_SHELL.sh

echo "0|$1|$2|$3" > /usr/local/pruebas/fichero_de_prueba
echo "EJECUCION DE ESCRITURA TERMINADA"
echo "00"
```

Los parametros enviados son: mensaje = "hola mundo", tiempo = 15

```
executeSitiShellLine("00",tiempo,mensaje);
```

El resultado en el fichero debería ser: 0|00|15|hola mundo

Pero lo que se escribe es: 0|00|15|"hola mundo"

Si en lugar de enviar texto en el mensaje, envio solo números, el resultado es: 0|00|15|1234

Ojalá, pudieran orientarme y decirme cuál pudiera ser el posible error. Gracias!

Edición de pregunta::::::::

```
 private CmdServiceResponse callServiceCmdLine(CmdServiceRequest request) 
{
    CmdServiceResponse response = new CmdServiceResponse();
    CmdServiceResponseType rt = new CmdServiceResponseType();
    Integer idOper = Integer.parseInt(request.getRRequest().getIdOper());
    try {
        CctmCataDTO dtoCata = serviceCata.findByPK(idOper);
        String url = URL_DIR_SO + "/SHELL/RESTART_DIS_VEHI.sh";
        DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
        System.out.println("URL " + url);
        CommandLine cmd = new CommandLine(url);
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF1() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF1());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF2() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF2());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF3() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF3());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF4() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF4());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF5() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF5());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF6() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF6());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF7() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF7());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF8() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF8());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF9() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF9());
        cmd.addArgument(request.getRRequest().getF10() == null ? "" : request.getRRequest().getF10());
        executor.setExitValue(0);
        PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler();
        streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler();
        executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);

        executor.execute(cmd);
        cmdDis = true;
        rt.setStatus("00");
    } catch (ExecuteException t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
        rt.setStatus("90");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        rt.setStatus("90");
    } catch (ServiceException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
        rt.setStatus("92");
    }
    response.setRResponse(rt);
    return response;
}

private String executeSitiShellLine(String param, String timeMsg ,String msg) {
    System.out.println("entra primer metodo");
    String execSiti = PropertiesUtils.getProperties().getProperty(PROPERTY_EXECUTE_SITI_NAME);
    if (execSiti == null || !execSiti.equals(PROPERTY_EXECUTE_SITI_VALUE)) {
        return "NA";
    }
    ExecuteSitiThreadLine st = new ExecuteSitiThreadLine();
    st.setParam(param, timeMsg ,msg);
    Thread t = new Thread(st);
    t.start();
    return "00";

}

private class ExecuteSitiThreadLine implements Runnable{

    private String param;
    private String msg;
    private String timeMsg;
    public void setParam(String param, String timeMsg ,String msg) {
        this.param = param;
        this.timeMsg = timeMsg;
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String sitiShellId = PropertiesUtils.getProperties().getProperty(PROPERTY_SITI_ID_SHELL, "906");
        CmdServiceRequest request = new CmdServiceRequest();
        CmdServiceRequestType rtype = new CmdServiceRequestType();
        rtype.setIdOper(sitiShellId);
        rtype.setF1(param);
        rtype.setF2(timeMsg);
        rtype.setF3(msg);
        System.out.println("rtype.getF1()" + rtype.getF1());
        System.out.println("rtype.getF2()" + rtype.getF2());
        System.out.println("rtype.getF3()" + rtype.getF3());
        request.setRRequest(rtype);
        callServiceCmdLine(request);
    }

}
```

Comment: si vas a enviar parámetros por consola no es necesario indicar con comillas que es un texto, solo tienes que quitárselas

Comment: Los parametros son enviados desde java, por lo que solo envio las variables al método que se las asigna al shell

Comment: pon el código entonces de executeSitiShellLine

Comment: Listo, agregue el código java que utilizo

Comment: ¿Podrías decir qué muestra la línea `System.out.println("rtype.getF3()" + rtype.getF3());`? Tiene toda la pinta que las `"` ya vienen en el valor que pasas como `msg`.

Comment: Esa línea escribe el contenido de **msg** sin comillas. Si el `msg = "Hola"` imprime: Hola

Comment: Faltan mas detalles para comprender mejor; por ejemplo como funcionan las clases `CommandLine`, `DefaultExecutor`, `PumpStreamHandler`, etc, etc. ¿Debes usar estrictamente ese código?, lo pregunto porque trate de emular lo de *escribir un archivo de texto desde un Shell script con parámetros enviados desde Java* mediante el uso de  `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` y pues todo salió Ok sin el problema que has planteado.

Comment: Trataré de hacerlo con el uso de lo que indicas en tu comentario, Johnny.